# Encoding Unicoded emoji from CSV file with text strings together

Tags: python, emoji, python-unicode

I have an issue with encoding of unicodes from CSV file. I have looked at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919372/unicode-emojis-in-python-from-csv-files) , but does not give a proper solution.
My CSV file is so,

```
Subject1,u"\U0001f3c6 Campaign for you"
Subject2,\U0001f3c6  Special Offer to you
Subject3,u'\U0001f3c6' UP to %25 Sales
Subject4,u\U0001f3c6 UP to %50 Sales
```

I am reading it into a dictionary. Then trying to encode to utf-8, not using open(encoding=utf-8) option delibaretely, somehow does not solve when using.

Here is code, where I had put all solutions to see in which case my code prints emoji, in none of them. I need to assist in my code

```
def emojis():
    file_ = file_reader.ReadFile().pathLooker('./Subjects/Subjects.csv')
    csv_ = open(file_,'r')
    data=dict(csv.reader(csv_,delimiter=','))
    print(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii'),type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')))
    print(data["Subject2"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')))
    print(data["Subject3"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')))
    print(data["Subject4"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')))
    print(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8'),type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8')))
    print(data["Subject2"].encode('utf-8'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8')))
    print(data["Subject3"].encode('utf-8'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8')))
    print(data["Subject4"].encode('utf-8'), type(data["Subject1"].encode('utf-8')))
    emoji = '\U0001f3c6 hello how'
```

Comment: As @margendo indicated you can use encode/decode pair to convert it to a character. But the problem isn't so much the need to convert the character but the fact that C style Unicode escapes were in the CSV file at all. If you generated the file the best place to fix the problem is at the point the CSV file is generated, rather than at the point it was consumed. It is an example of dirty data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode your string with escape characters using `unicode_escape` as the decoding.

For example, the second line of your csv file can be decoded using the following line:

```py
data['Subject2'].encode().decode("unicode_escape")
```

Output:

```py
  Special Offer to you
```